# Infinite AMQP Consumer with Alpakka

Tags: akka-stream, alpakka

I'm trying to implement a very simple service connected to an AMQP broker with Alpakka. I just want it to consume messages from its queue as a stream at the moment they are pushed on a given exchange/topic.

Everything seemed to work fine in my tests, but when I tried to start my service, I realized that my stream was only consuming my messages once and then exited.

Basically I'm using the code from Alpakka documentation :

```scala
def consume()={
    val amqpSource = AmqpSource.committableSource(
      TemporaryQueueSourceSettings(connectionProvider, exchangeName)
        .withDeclaration(exchangeDeclaration)
        .withRoutingKey(topic),
      bufferSize = prefetchCount
    )

    val amqpSink = AmqpSink.replyTo(AmqpReplyToSinkSettings(connectionProvider))

    amqpSource.mapAsync(4)(msg => onMessage(msg)).runWith(amqpSink)
}
```

I tried to schedule the `consume()` execution every second, but I experienced `OutOfMemoryException` issues.

Is there any proper way to make this code run as an infinite loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a `Source` restarted when it fails or is cancelled, wrap it with [`RestartSource.withBackoff`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/RestartSource/withBackoff.html#restartsource-withbackoff).

Comment: I already tried to use `RestartSource.withBackoff` but that didn't restart the Source when it's completed, only when it fails. I'm looking for a Source that never ends.

Comment: `onFailuresWithBackoff` does that. `withBackoff` restarts both, on failure and completion.

Comment: You are right, RestartSource did it, thank you ! My problem with `RestartSource` came from my Sink. Everything seems to work fine now.